# Azure Functions Elastic Premium plan scaling events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm currently working on alerts based on scaling events.
We have an Azure Function with Elastic Premium plan. I want to get alerts when the number of active instances reaches some amount.

What I've tried?
Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-scale-controller-logs) documentation, I've tried to add logging for scaling events by adding configuration `SCALE_CONTROLLER_LOGGING_ENABLED=AppInsights:Verbose`

After that, I've tried query from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data#query-scale-controller-logs) documentation. But for some reason, it doesn't work for me. [image]

Also, I am sure, that there was scaling events already, since I see the amount of instances of current function [image]

One possible way that comes to my mind is to query the number of instances from traces

```
traces
| where timestamp >= ago(10m)
| where cloud_RoleName == 'func-application-dev'
| summarize dcount(cloud_RoleInstance)
```

But I don't really like this approach.
I want to see scaling events in the logs. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: The Kusto query need to be more specific, see the example given [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-check-elastic-premium-plan-function-app-allocated/ba-p/2697852)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I've tried this query as well. The same result

Comment: Are you looking at the right function app and it's AppInsights resource, just in case. Otherwise, I see no reason why it will not return results.

Comment: The query from your link does not contain any name filters. Logs should be written to the appinsights and the scope of my query is correct - I'm looking for traces from the appinsights.

Comment: You could raise an issue on the Appinsights [github](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues).

Comment: How are you viewing the instance count there?